# Complex function as mapping the plane into surfaces (..?)

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose we have the complex function $f(z) = e^{iz}$ defined as $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. I believe , there is some sort of natural association of the output of the function to relating the plane to the cylinder:

[image]

On LHS, I have drawn the domain a plane. We can see as we move along the redline, the function is periodic every $2 \pi $ units. So, that periodicity aspect on the cylinder is seen as moving around loops on the curved side. Now, as we move along the orange line, we increase our height on the cylinder. The  red circle can be thought of as $y$ coordinate of the output of the function and the orange line as the $x$ coordinate.

It seems so that the symmetries of the complex function can be used to make the action of function as bending and gluing of the domain.

Is there any pre-existing which can make this idea I have here more concrete and general?

Comment: You might be interested in [Riemann Surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface) as a very close cousin of your construction.

Comment: I have heard of that and I have seen many videos on it. That I understood is more like we are doing it for function with branch cut and branch points. Here I don't see those issues and that's why I didn't think of it that being the answer